# Dualboot with fast startup

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows 8. I know that if we try to use Ubuntu without disabling fast startup in Windows, the changes we made on the shared partition will get lost when we boot from Windows.

Will there still be problems if I leave fast startup enabled, but perform a complete shutdown on Windows whenever I am going to boot from Ubuntu?

It says **Restart isn't affected** in the option to enable/disable Fast Startup. This is what made me think that I won't have a problem if I perform a full shutdown before booting from Ubuntu

Comment: you answered your own question. If you leave fast startup enabled, you will loose data when you boot from Ubuntu to Windows regardless if you perform a "complete shutdown" of windows as the data was changed outside of windows.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I understand that windows performs some kind of hibernation when shutting down the computer with fast startup enabled. But as far as I know if we restart the computer or shut down by right clicking on windows icon on the bottom left corner in desktop and choosing shut down option, windows does not hibernate itself. My question is if we shut down windows like that, will I still lose data?

Comment: I do not know of any other way of telling you - as long as fast startup is enabled you will loose data when you boot ubuntu regardless of how you shut windows down. This is what fast startup does.